# Show loaded data in curly braces using Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-options-api

Can someone explain the difference between the following, please?

**Options API version**

Displays loaded data in DOM as expected

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            config: {},
        };
    },
    async mounted() {
        this.config = await fetch('/path/to/file.json');
    },
    template: `<div>{{ config }}</div>`
}
```

**Composition API version**

Displays initial state of config but not the loaded data

```js
import { onMounted, reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        let config = reactive({});

        onMounted(async () => {
            config = await fetch('/path/to/file.json');
        });

        return {
            config,
        };
    },
    template: `<div>{{ config }}</div>`
}
```

I suspect that the `reactive()` is being overridden by the asynchronous data load (and I can console log the new data in the `onMounted` function) but I can't see anything in the docs to indicate how to mass-update a reactive object like this (especially when it works in the Options API)

Edit: final thoughts:

I've taken to using `reactive` objects to provide / inject data around the app and then using `toRefs` as a JIT way to provide the reactive data to my views. This seems to be the best of both worlds.

example:

```js
import { onMounted, reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';

export default {
    setup() {
        const data = reactive({
            config: {},
        });

        onMounted(async () => {
            data.config = await fetch('/path/to/file.json');
        });

        return {
            ...toRefs(data),
        };
    },
    template: `<div>{{ config }}</div>`
}
```

Comment: given that all data in a `reactive` object is essentially a get/set, do I need to crawl the entire object, adding keys with `ref()` on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are overriding the whole config you should use `ref` instead of `reactive`.
See [HERE](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```
  setup() {
    let config = ref({});

    onMounted(async () => {
        config.value = await fetch('path/to/file.json');
    });

    return {
        config,
    };
}
```

Never the less its working with reactive too:

```
  setup() {
    let config = reactive({});

    onMounted(async () => {
        config.value = await fetch('path/to/file.json');
    });

    return {
        config,
    };
}
```

Comment: I believe that refs are the reactive values within a `reactive` object and shouldn't be objects themselves. 

I tried it anyway but found the same result

Comment: Well i guess. You can use reactive but u have to call `config.value`

Comment: ahhhhhh - i could have sworn i did that  but yes that's working. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference between two example that you mentioned is the `this` keyword. According to [Vue 3 documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#usage-of-this), Inside setup(), **this** won't be a reference to the current active instance. So in the second code that you mentioned (composition API), you can not set only "config" word to an output of a fetch process. It is better to set a `key` for your object to work. for example for me this code works correctly:

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ config }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
    name: "configCompo",
    setup(props) {
        let config = reactive({});

        onMounted(
            async () => {
                console.log("mounted")
                let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                console.log(response);
                let data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
                config.output = data;
            }
            

        );

        return {
            config,
        };
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: @orbus is correct to say use `ref()` as `reactive` objects need to be set up with a schema  are so aren't useful for dynamic data (apart from, as you said, if you assign it to a key)

Comment: @obie I think reading [this article](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-3-composition-api-ref-vs-reactive/) could help for better understanding differences between ```ref``` and ```reactive```. In my opinion using ```ref``` or ```reactive``` generally depends on the type of data and the structure of your code, not dynamic or static data.